# Translate Unity units of measurement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, units-of-measurement, cad

In Unity one can use Raycasting to calculate various measurements. Examples such as diameter, thickness of a wall, and width. One way to do this is by capturing a users mouse click on an object and using RaycastHits to capture the location of the mouse click on the object and than casting additional rays depending on the measurement desired.

Seen below:
Thickness of the walls clicked is .0098, .0096, and .0072. Width is .0615, .0611, and .060. Diameter is .0475.

Though these measurements are (believed to be)  executed and calculated correctly it's unclear how the results translate to real world units of measurement.

This is best demonstrated and shown in the fourth image. Checking the same diameter in other CAD programs, such as NX, the diameter is 0.4210" or inches. Thickness and width were calculated as well at .075244" and .252872" respectively.

So than, **how do the results in Unity**, (results produced using Vector3.Distance to calculate the distance between two points) **translate to real world units of measurement**?

Googling the subject yields a common answer: Unity's measurements are "game units" and can be used however desired. While I grasp this, I don't understand how to accomplish the translation of "game units", or whatever Unity's units of measurement truly are, to the measurement results I can see in CAD programs.

Results (CAD x Unity):
Thickness: .075244" x .0098, .0096, and .0072. 
Width: .252872" x .0615, .0611, and .060. 
Diameter: 0.4210" x .0475

(note1: model scales are identical in Unity and external CAD program.)

(note2: the slight variation in thickness and width results from Unity measurements coming at angles where the CAD program is measuring distance between the two planes, i.e. .009x and .06x.)

(note3: ignore the incorrect labeling of Width in the second visual as 'Thickness' and the inch labeling in all of the Unity visuals, ", as both incorrect).

[image: thickness]
[image: width]
[image: diameter-unity]
[image: diameter_cadprgm]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Unity unit is generally held to be 1 meter, however as you've read it's up to your implementation, in this case it looks like you're actually exporting from CAD with 1 inch = 1 unit, since your results seem similar but slightly off.

The reason you're getting innaccuracies is most likely due to Unity's collision system not being extremely accurate, most colliders are in fact slightly larger than the mesh they represent which will throw off your fine tuned measurements significantly, and on top of that Unity will have much lower precision than CAD, since Unity is a game engine and needs to perform in realtime, 3D position data is not very accurate (it gets pretty hazy around 4 digits of precision), and in fact gets significantly worse as you travel away from the origin.

I wouldn't recommend trying to use Unity for any kind of precise design work, especially when representing the real world, but if you're dead set, you might want to scale your objects up by a factor of 10 or 100 in order to keep your digits closer to the decimal point to reduce floating point error, this is a hack obviously.

You may want to also look at your physics settings: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html
In particular "Default Contact Offset" may be relevant (although I'm not sure if it affects raycasts)

PS: I'd post this as a comment but the rep system won't let me, your description of the measurements between each environment is really confusing, next time maybe try and format it in a table or something?

Comment: If your cad files are inconsistent between millimeters and inches, Unity cannot solve that problem. It can only see that the model is `x units` big, it has no idea what units those are and can only suggest its own measurement unit: the Metre.